# Insert the highest value among the number of times it occurs

Tags: perl

I have two files:

1) Tab file with the following content. Let's call this reference file:

```
V$HMGIY_01_rc   Ncor=0.405
V$CACD_01   Ncor=0.405
V$GKLF_02   Ncor=0.650
V$AML2_Q3   Ncor=0.792
V$WT1_Q6    Ncor=0.607
V$KID3_01   Ncor=0.668
V$CNOT3_01  Ncor=0.491
V$KROX_Q6   Ncor=0.423
V$ETF_Q6_rc Ncor=0.547
V$E2F_Q2_rc Ncor=0.653
V$SP1_Q6_01_rc  Ncor=0.650
V$SP4_Q5    Ncor=0.660
```

2) The second tab file contains the search string X as shown below. Let's call this file as search_string:

```
       A                 X
    NF-E2_SC-22827    NF-E2
    NRSF              NRSF
    NFATC1_SC-17834   NFATC1
    NFKB              NFKB
    TCF3_SC-349       TCF3
    MEF2A             MEF2A
```

what I have already done is: Take the first search term (from search_string file; column X), check if it occurs in first column of the reference file. Example: The first search term is NF-E2. I checked if this string occurs in the first column of the reference file. If it occurs, then give a score of 1, else give 0. Also i have counted the number of times it matches the pattern. Now my output is of the format:

```
     Keyword     Keyword in file?     Number of times keyword occurs in file
      NF-E2          1                            3
      NRSF           0                            0
      NFATC1         0                            0
      NFKB           1                            7
      TCF3           0                            0
```

Now, in addition to this, what I would like to add is the highest Ncor value for each string in each file. Say for example: while I search for NF-E2 in NF-E2.txt, the Ncor values present are: 3.02, 2.87 and 4.59. Then I want the value 4.59 to be printed in the next column. So now my output should look   like:

```
  Keyword    Keyword in file?   Number of times keyword occurs in file  Ncor
  NF-E2          1                            3                         4.59
  NRSF           0                            0
  NFATC1         0                            0
  NFKB           1                            7                         1.66
  TCF3           0                            0
```

Please note: I need to search each string in different files i.e. The first string (Nf-E2) should be searched in file NF-E2.tab; the second string (NRSF) should be searched in file NRSF.tab and so on.

Here is my code:

```
perl -lanE '$str=$F[1];  $f="/home/$str/list/$str.txt"; $c=`grep -c "$str" "$f"`;chomp($c);$x=0;$x++ if $c;say "$str\t$x\t$c"' file2
```

PLease help!!!

Comment: I can't see either `NF-E2` or `NFKB` in the first file

Comment: Please post the code you've written so far.  It should not be hard to add a "max-Ncor" output to the code you've written, but it would be harder for someone to try to write this from scratch.

Comment: @jimtut: I have added the code now in the question.

Comment: It is crazy to try to accomplish such a complex task with one-liner. It is possible, but too crazy.

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

while (<>) {
    chomp;
    my $keyword = (split /\s+/)[1];
    my $file = "/home/$keyword/list/${keyword}.txt";
    open my $reference, '<', "$file" or die "Cannot open $file: $!";

    my $key_cnt = 0;
    my $max_ncor = 0;
    while (my $line = <$reference>) {
        my ($string, undef, $ncor) = split /\s+|=/, $line;
        if ($string =~ $keyword) {
            $key_cnt++;
            $max_ncor = $ncor if ($max_ncor < $ncor);
        }
    }
    print join("\t", $keyword, $key_cnt ? 1 : 0, $key_cnt, $key_cnt ? $max_ncor : ''), "\n";
}
```

---

Run it like this:

```
perl t.pl search_string.txt
```

Comment: Also, I have my files in different subdirectories. So, will this work if it is like this? I am not sure how to provide my input files. Please help

Comment: @biobudhan Please 1. tell me which part you does not understand first, that code quite straightforward; 2. include your directory structure in your question.

Comment: My files are stored as follows: The files are stored as follows: home/NF-E2/list/NF-E2.txt home/NRSF/list/NRSF.txt and so on.
I am not quite sure how the files are taken for input.

Comment: I understood the script. I am not sure how to execute it in the command line. Really sorry, am a newbie to programming.

Comment: @biobudhan Run it like this: `perl t.pl search_string.txt`

Comment: It doesn't work as expected. I am getting 0 in both the columns along with the filename. :-(

Comment: @biobudhan Do not blame me for your fault. That script does not output any file names, you must modified it wrongly.

Comment: Which script are you talking about?

Comment: @biobudhan The script in my answer, of course. What else could it be?

Comment: Ok. I have saved the above script as t.pl; the search_string.txt contains: 
NFE2.txt    NFE2
NRSF.txt    NRSF
and so on. 
I have changed my working directory to where these files are saved. Is there something I need to change?

Comment: Really sorry. I am not able to figure out. :'(